# Handling join table entries based on association attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, join

### TL;DR

What is the best way to create join table entries based on a form with the attributes of a association, like a bar code or a plate number?

### Detailed explanation

In this system that records movements of items between storage places, there is a `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `storage_movements` and `storage_items` because items can be moved multiple times and multiple items can be moved at once.

These items are previously created and are identified by a plate number that is physically attached to the item and recorded on its creation on the application.

The problem is that I need to create `storage_movements` with a form where the user inputs only the plate number of the `storage_item` that is being moved but I cant figure it out a way to easily do this.

I have been hitting my head against this wall for some time and the only solution that I can think of is creating nested fields on the new `storage_movements` form for the `storage_items` and use specific code on the model to create, update and delete these `storage_movements` by explicitly querying these plate numbers and manipulating the join table entries for these actions.

Is this the correct way of handling the problem? The main issue with this solution is that I can't seem to display validation errors on the specific plates number that are wrong (I'm using simple_forms) because I don't have `storage_item` objects to add errors.

Below there is a snipped of the code for the form that I'm currently using. Any help is welcome :D

```
# views/storage_movements/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @storage_movement do |movement_form| %>
  #Other form inputs
  <%= movement_form.simple_fields_for :storage_items do |item_form| %>
    <%= item_form.input :plate, label: "Plate number" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# models/storage_movement.rb
class StorageMovement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :storage_items, inverse_of: :storage_movements, validate: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :storage_items, allow_destroy: true

  ... several callbacks and validations ...
end

# models/storage_item.rb
class StorageItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_and_belongs_to_many :storage_movements, inverse_of: :storage_items

  ... more callbacks and validations ...
end
```

The controllers were the default generated ones.

Comment: You kind of lost me when you put `stock_*` objects in the game. How are these related to the `storage_*` objects/ Do do we care about these as well?
I got confused about what the actual problem is. Is it that you don't know how to handle the plate number from the form to actually connect it to the proper item instead of using its id or is it something else?

Comment: Sorry about that, they are the same, I just misnamed them. Already fixed the text.

Comment: Then, the code you provided seems fine and should work. If you have added `validates_associated` and properly configured your models, validations and form you should be fine. If you tried these or/and are having issues, please post relevant code (controllers, models, form with error displays, etc.) and we can take it from there.

Comment: added them as requested. With this, when I tried to create storage movements, it would try to create new storage items, instead of using the existing ones based on plates, but failed due to presence validations. Also, when we tried to update movements, it would edit the plates of items, instead of creating new join table records...

Comment: I don't think the default generated controller accounts for building new records for your nested_resources. The answer you provided seems terrible and will probably bite you in the bottom (:P) in the future. At the very least you might want to check virtual_attributes before moving on with this. However the problem could be in your controller setup. Does simple_form_for automatically show the errors for each field (didn't notice anything error-related in your view code, that's why I was wondering)?

Comment: I agree, my answer is terrible :'D 
How would virtual attributes help me? Wouldn't I still need the custom creator and update methods?
Simple forms adds the error messages in the form-group div of the input if there is a error associated with that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution, it really "feels" wrong and the validations also are not shown like I want it to... But it was what I could come up with... Hopefully it helps someone.

I created the `create_from_plates` and `update_from_plates` methods on the model to handle the create and update and updated the actions of the controller to use them.

Note: had to switch to a `has_many through` association due to callback necessities.

```
# models/storage_movement.rb
class StorageMovement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movements_items, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :storage_movement
  has_many :storage_items, through: :movements_items, inverse_of: :allocations, validate: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :storage_items, allow_destroy: true

  validate :check_plates

  def StorageMovement::create_from_plates mov_attributes
    attributes = mov_attributes.to_h
    items_attributes = attributes.delete "items_attributes"

    unless items_attributes.nil?
      item_plates = items_attributes.collect {|k, h| h["plate"]}
      items = StorageItem.where, plate: item_plates
    end

    if not items_attributes.nil? and item_plates.length == items.count
      new_allocation = Allocation.new attributes
      movements_items.each {|i| new_allocation.items << i}
      return new_allocation
    else
      Allocation.new mov_attributes
    end
  end

  def update_from_plates mov_attributes
    attributes = mov_attributes.to_h
    items_attributes = attributes.delete "items_attributes"

    if items_attributes.nil?
      self.update mov_attributes
    else
      transaction do
        unless items_attributes.nil?
          items_attributes.each do |k, item_attributes|
            item = StorageItem.find_by_plate(item_attributes["plate"])
            if item.nil?
              self.errors.add :base, "The plate #{item_attributes["plate"]} was not found"
              raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
            elsif item_attributes["_destroy"] == "1" or item_attributes["_destroy"] == "true"
              self.movements_items.destroy item
            elsif not self.items.include? item
              self.movements_items << item
            end
          end
        end
        self.update attributes
      end
    end
  end


  def check_plates
    movements_items.each do |i|
      i.errors.add :plate, "Plate not found" if StorageItem.find_by_plate(i.plate).nil?
    end
  end

  ... other validations and callbacks ...
end
```

With this, the create works as I wanted, because, in case of a error, the validation adds the error to the specific item attribute. But the update does not because it has to add the error to the base of the movement, since there is no item.